# Wordpress deployed to host server, but the page still tries to access localhost URLs

Tags: php, wordpress

So I developped everything locally.

When I uploaded it to the actuall hostserver under http://lukasmeier.someurl.ch I still get calls to localhost.

Which setting do I have to manipulate?

I added to wp-config.php

```
define('WP_HOME','http://lukasmeier.example.com/demoapps');

define('WP_SITEURL','http://lukasmeier.example.com/demoapps');
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress stocks URL information in the DB, be sure to proceed to **Search and replace on a dump** of your current DB and replace the URLs (ex: http://localhost.com/site > http://www.site.com **DON'T INCLUDE THE LAST SLASH** ) , then **reupload the dump on your server**.

OR

**Here's a PHP script that do the job** : https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB

I use that two ways, it works fine.

Edit:

- go to your admin, Appearance > Menus and save it (if you have one)
- regenerate the permalinks

Comment: Yes, but some links are serialized and simple change will not work.

Comment: That's right, I made an edit to my answer. Doing that, I never had trouble migrating Wordpress from wherever to wherever :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to update two values in the `wp_options` table of your database.

I think that the values correspond to Base url and Home url, but most probably you will find them if you filter the table for `localhost` as this string is probably in there ;)

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of changing config, wordpress stores this in options. In it's mysql database, you'll find a table called wp_options and there's column option_name called siteurl.

Source & more info [here.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress)

Comment: Should not the constants defined in wp-config override those database info?

Comment: They should, but it's not always the case.. Change both prior to deployment = good to go, not change one = something might fail.